# why's the php process hang there for almost 3 months?

Tags: linux, system-calls

I got a php process, the php process is called by a shell script.

the php is supposed to be running for like 3 or 4 minutes and then terminate and the shell start another one.

Problem is that I found the process was started at Apr and hang there, then I `strace -p` into it, here's the output:

```
restart_syscall(0x7fff47163410, 0x1, 0xea60, 0, 0x7f255a978bf8...)
```

any opinions?

Comment: You don't give enough details (what is that php process supposed to do? How has it been started?), and you probably should not care (so could `kill -TERM`, then `kill -QUIT` and finally `kill -KILL` the offending PHP process).

Comment: Yeah, the Logic in that php is a little bit complicated, but it is not a daemon process. I already kill it but still want to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restart_syscall() system call restarts time-constrained interrupted process, and it includes the time-spent before interruption into  account. Your original process might have got interrupted, and then got resumed.  Could be a issue with your time parameters.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the `time-constrained interrupted process`. Could you explain more about this? Thanks!

Comment: Time-constrained means the process is meant to run for a specific amount of time. The process got interrupted somehow, either by a resource-crunch, or maybe some other issue/process issued a SIGSTOP or SIGTSTP signal. Has it occurred only once? If  this occurs regularly, then your code needs to be analysed. You may also need to monitor what other events in OS are causing interrupt.

Comment: By  `meant to run for a specific amount of time` , is this means code like `sleep` or something ? And when the process is sleeping, it is interrupted.

Comment: No :sleeping" does not count as interrupt. An interrupt will be anything which causes the current process to exit (something similar to CTRL+C). And yes, sleep() is a run-for-specific-time process